# Access denied error when doing full import into Solr

Tags: java, mysql, solr

I'm attempting to use Solr to run a full data import via the Solr admin interface. When I run it however, I get the following output:

```
"Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes."
```

On further inspection of the Solr logs, I can see that I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

(Username replaced for security, full stack [here](http://pastebin.com/CfSBzns2))

Has anyone else had the same issue? I've double checked the database details (have accessed the database in question from the command line successfully).

I've also checked the privileges for the user and can confirm that it has all privileges granted for it on the database in question.

Comment: How have you tested the connection? From the same server as Solr runs on? Have you double checked that you've entered the password correctly and with the correct argument to the JDBC connection definition in the DIH configuration?

Comment: @fiskfisk ssh'd into the same server that mysql and solr is running on. Entered the following command:

`mysql -u xxxx -p xxxx -h localhost`

and managed to get in successfully. Have double checked the JDBC connection string in my solr dataconfig:

url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx" user="xxxx" password="xxxx"

Comment: I think this is mysql related. Probably that user lacks a privilege to connect/connect from remote/access that schema/access that table.

Comment: @cheffe yeah I agree that it must be MySQL related. I can't work out why Solr can't access it though. They're both running on the same server. I've checked that the user in question has all privileges on localhost, 127.0.0.1 and %. Can't work out what I'm missing...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was related to privilieges for the database users. I had granted prvilieges to the user in the question, but had left out the "IDENTIFIED BY 'password'" part of the command.

So this is what I needed to use:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.